# Active Flash/Flex/ActionScript 3 AOP project?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, aop

I've seen the Loom project, but are there any alternatives that are more mature (and actively developed)?  I am looking for something that would allow load-time weaving of pointcuts into existing binary code at runtime with the AVM2 runtime.

Has any work been done in this area?

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone has used Floxy / Flemit for weaving and pointcuts but I'd love to work with you to do this.  Email me if you want to collaborate jaward at adobe dot com

Answer (score 4):

Check out:
http://code.google.com/p/floxy/
http://code.google.com/p/flemit/

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm a little late to the party here, but I've just put together a really simple AOP project for integration with Parsley.

It allows you to assign metatags to interceptors, like so:

```
    <parsley:ContextBuilder>
        <parsley:FlexConfig type="{ParsleyConfig}" />
        <tag:AspectSupport>
            <tag:MetatagInterceptorDefinition metatag="Log" interceptor="{new TracingInterceptor()}" />
        </tag:AspectSupport>            
    </parsley:ContextBuilder>
```

Then, any classes in the Parsley context that are annotated with `Log` get that method proxied:

```
    [Log]
    public function add(a:int,b:int):int
    {
        return a + b;
    }
```

The project is [here](http://code.google.com/p/flapper-as/) and a blog post explaining in more detail is [here](http://martypitt.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/flapper-an-extension-library-for-aop-with-parsley/)

Comment: This looks interesting. How deep is the dependency on Parsley? We are using Robotlegs and I'm wondering whether your project could be amended to work with it?

Comment: It's more dependant on Parsley than it needs to be.  I had intended to build a version that worked with Swiz, but if there's more of a demand for RobotLegs, then I could look at that first.  I've added an issue to serve as a discussion point:  http://bit.ly/eB70kb

Comment: The above approach is not based on a AVM2 byte-code weaving, right? It's using a proxy.

Comment: @Vladimir:  It uses dynamic bytecode generation.  The class which is annotated is dynamically subclassed, so that type safety is still satisfied when it is injected.

Comment: @Marty Pitt: I see, but this library [Flapper-AS](http://code.google.com/p/flapper-as/) is not part of Parsley, right?

Answer (score 2):

As the author of flemit / floxy (though both were only created for [asmock](http://asmock.sourceforge.net/)), I would recommend looking into [AS3Commons Bytecode](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/emit.html) as it is under active development (flemit/floxy are not).

AS3Commons Bytecode is actually based on the [Loom](http://code.google.com/p/loom-as3/) project and has been extended to use a much cleaner API than flemit was ever intended to have.